# About the fixed part of a linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have this definition:
take $ \mathcal{S} \subset|D|$ a linear system contained in the complete linear system associated to the divisor $D \in Div(S)$ where $S$ is a complex algebraic projective surface.
$\mathcal{S}$ has fixed part if there exist an effective divisor $Z$ such that
$ \forall D^{'}\in \mathcal{S}, \ D^{'}=Z+R$ with $R>0$.
So this is just the definition but i have no more properties on my notes. For example is there a relation between the fixed part and the base locus of the system $\mathcal{S}$, ($\mathcal{B}_s(\mathcal{S})$)?
If i take the map defined from my surface $S - \mathcal{B_s(S)}$ to $\mathbb{P}^N$   as
$\phi \ : S - \mathcal{B_s(S)} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^N$

$\qquad \qquad x \mapsto(s_0(x):\ldots:s_N(x))$ where i suppose that $\mathcal{S}=\mathbb{P}(U)$ and $U \subset H^0(D)$ is a vector sub space of $H^0(D)$ generated by $(s_0,\ldots,s_N)$  what is the role of the fixed part?

Comment: for example i cant's see geometrically the base locus and the fixed part and so their relationship

Comment: If your surface is nonsingular in codimension one, the answer is easy: For any $Z$ satisfying that property, all elements of your linear system considered as sections of the line bundle $\mathcal L(D)$ vanish at $Z$. Hence, $Z$ is contained in the base locus of your linear system $\mathcal S$. I'd have to ponder a bit if anything goes wrong in the singular case, but I have only ever heard the term "linear system" used in the context of "sufficiently nice" varieties.

Comment: The fixed part is the codimension-1 part of the base locus. Put another way, if $B_s(\mathcal S)$ has codimension at least 2 in $S$, then then $\mathcal S$ has no fixed part.

Comment: so if i delete the base locus from my system i remove also the fixed part right? henche the application in the post become a rational map